# Expression “if and when something happens”

Tags: expressions, formality

What is the level of formality in the expression “if and when” while referring to a possible happening? Googling “if and when *X* happen” gives me all sorts of entries, some formal some clearly informal.

Comment: logically, wouldn't it be the same as saying simply *when*?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

*If and when* carries no direct formality implication as your search shows.

Note 1: Unless you associate the complexity and precision with formalism. As in if you assume that a formal audience will more likely understand (and also correctly use) the expression in all of its subtleties.

Note 2: The phrase was actually heavily criticized by Fowler (see [here](http://www.bartleby.com/116/504.html#42)) and perhaps more appropriately treated in [Merriam-Webster](http://books.google.com/books?id=2yJusP0vrdgC&pg=PA521&dq=%22if%20and%20when%22&hl=en&ei=WuVITqnOOsal8QOO-fnPBg&sa=X&oi=book_result&ct=result&resnum=3&ved=0CDcQ6AEwAg#v=onepage&q=%22if%20and%20when%22&f=false). This complexity is something that you might not want to deal with in informal text or talk.